# How do I access session data in Jinja2 templates (Bottle framework on app engine)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, jinja2, beaker

I'm running the micro framework [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/page/docs) on Google App Engine.  I'm using [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) for my templates.  And I'm using [Beaker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Beaker/0.9.4) to handle the sessions.  I'm still a pretty big Python newbie and am pretty stoked I got this far :)  My question is how do I access the session data within the templates?  I can get the session data no problem within the actual python code.  And I could pass the session data each time I call a jinja template.  But since I need the session data in the main menu bar of the site... that means I would have to pass it on every single page.  Does anyone know if I can access it directly in the templates?

For example I need the session data for my header links:

Home |  FAQ |  Login

or

Home | FAQ | Logout

Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add things to the Jinja2 [environment globals](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#jinja2.Environment.globals) if you want them to be accessible to all templates. See [this page](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/api#global-namespace) for additional information.

**Update:**

A simple example is, for your setup code:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', 'templates'))
```

Then, in your request handling code:

```
env.globals['session'] = session # Your session
# Your template can contain things like {{ session['key'] }}
template = env.get_template('mytemplate.html')
print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
#return response using rendered data
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble finding some examples.  Can you tell me how I would set the global variable? :D